# Sum number in table and save in variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have table money in first row I have number 10 in second 20 and third 30 and now I'm going to sum this rows and save into variable $sum

This is my code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(money) as total FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$idd'");
$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sum= $row['total'];
```

If I print `$sum` Result is 102030 but I need to print 60

Comment: Did you put the values as integers in your database? Because it looks like you are using varchars here..

Comment: Never store numbers as text!

Comment: I am put money int but not work

Comment: Money usually has fractional parts. Also, what did not work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to change your table's structure.

```
alter table $tablename alter column money decimal(10,2)
```

Choose the decimal precision that fits your needs.

If you are really stuck because you do not have access to change the table structure, you could change your query to :

```
SELECT SUM(cast(money as decimal(10,2))) as total FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$idd'
```

Comment: Now I have 4.008.00 If I put money 4 and 8